# Converting Python byte string to UTF-8/ASCII

Tags: python, string, utf-8, ascii, data-conversion

I am working on sending bytes to a USB device from a Python application. An example payload looks as follows:

```py
a = bytearray(b'\x00\xb4nn\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

What I am curious about is the `nn` part, following `\xb4nn` - the string, in the current form, cannot be converted to either UTF-8 or ASCII. In some payload cases, that string can also be `\xb4n`, which seems like an odd way to present HEX information.

What is `nn` in a byte string?

Comment: It doesn't sound like this bytestring actually represents text, so trying to interpret it as UTF-8 or ASCII doesn't make sense.

Comment: Makes sense. Let's assume that it's not representing text then - what can I do to understand what that `nn` part represents?

Comment: Two `\x6e` bytes. Bytes that correspond to regular ascii characters are displayed as those characters in a bytestring repr. There's probably a dupe around here somewhere.

Comment: `nn` means exactly `nn` - two chars `n`. If you need its hex code - `hex(ord('n'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printable ASCII byte values are displayed as ASCII.  It is only a display convention, similar to the leading `b` indicating a byte string.  The byte values are still the same.  For example, ASCII `n` is the byte value 0x6E, and if you create a byte string with these values, it will be displayed as:

```
>>> b'\x6e\x6e'
b'nn'
```

Also:

```
>>> b'\x6e\x6e' == b'nn'
True
```